# How to find out website webapp manifest URL without being redirected to cookies consent webpage

Tags: node.js, https, fetch-api

I'm writing a nodeJS app module that, when given a URL, visits it (via `fetch`), grabs webapp manifest url (if present) and returns parsed manifest's contents.

My issue is with some sites (i.e. yahoo.com) that redirect to a cookie consent domain (i.e. consent.yahoo.com), thus not making it possible to find out the manifest's full URL.

Is there a way to find out the URL of manifest file or to get around the redirection? Of course I can grab consent cookies from my browser and put them in the app, but I want the app to JustWork™️ without need to provide additional cookies/headers/settings/etc